# Running perl files from a text file

Tags: perl

There're multiple perl scripts that is ran from CYGWIN terminal. An example is,

```
$ perl IdGeneratorTool.pl JSmith -i userInfo.adb -o JSmith.txt
```

The above is an example. Were based on input parameter ***JSmith***, it reads a db file, generate an ID and output that to a text file.

Now these perl scripts running on the CYGWIN keeps growing and it's added to a text file like shown below,

```
$ perl IdGeneratorTool.pl JSmith -i userInfo.adb -o JSmith.txt
$ perl IdGeneratorTool.pl PTesk -i userInfo.adb -o PTesk.txt
$ perl IdGeneratorTool.pl CMorris -i userInfo.adb -o CMorris.txt
$ perl IdGeneratorTool.pl JLawrence -i userInfo.adb -o JLawrence.txt
$ perl IdGeneratorTool.pl TCruise -i userInfo.adb -o TCruise.txt
...
....
......
.......
.........
```

And the list keeps growing.

I would like to know whether there's a way to execute all these perl scripts which are in a text file in one go.

I'm new to perl and doesn't have much idea as to what are the options.

An ideal scenario might be, a tool where i can open this text file and click a **execute** button and then it executes all the scripts and output multiple *.txt files into the same directory.

Or maybe a simple perl script that can do it.

Comment: So how will that change each line of perl script inside the text file? How to make it all run at one time?

Comment: I don't know CYGWIN but you can probably run `bash YOURTEXTFILE`

Comment: Are you sure you want to launch all scripts at one go? that would use all the memory if the list is too big

Comment: If you want to launch multiple tasks using threads at one time you can use `Thread::Semaphore` it is pretty simple : https://metacpan.org/pod/Thread::Semaphore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put them into a file `makeall` (or whatever you want to call it.
2. Put as a first line `#!/bin/bash` into the file
3. In cygwin enter `chmod +x makeall`
4. in cygwin enter `./makeall`

With this you've created a bash script which'll do all your calls of the perl script.

Another option would to just put all the user information into a csv file and read that one in order to call your script.

WAIT! Even easier!

Put into the `makeall` script this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for user in \
        JSmith \
        PTesk \
        CMorris \
        JLawrence \
        TCruise \
; do
        perl IdGeneratorTool.pl "$user" -i userInfo.adb -o "$user".txt
done
```

Now you just need to add any additional user the same way I did for your examples.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the source for `IdGeneratorTool.pl` it's hard to give any specific advice; but it is generally not hard to turn something like

```
do_stuff($ARGV[0], $opt_i, $opt_o);
```

into

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    $user, $adb, $outputfile = split('\t');
    do_stuff($user, $adb, $outputfile);
}
```

to read the input from a tab-delimited file instead of from command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can create text file with list of users (one per line) for example **user_list.txt**

```
JSmith
PTesk
CMorris
JLawrence
TCruise
```

Then create bash script **process_list.sh** with following content in same directory

```
#!/bin/bash

for user in `cat user_list.txt`
do
    perl IdGeneratorTool.pl $user -i userInfo.adb -o ${user}.txt
done
```

Now make bash script executable `chmod +x process_list.sh` and it is ready for execution.

Once you need to add new user edit **user_list.txt** to add one more line into the file.

Polar Bear